# python for loop converting from C for loop

Tags: c, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

the following is a part of C code for singly linked list:

```
for(tptr = start; tptr != NULL && tptr->data < newnode->data; prev=tptr, tptr= tptr->next);
```

**How do I convert this for loop in C to for loop in Python?**

Comment: Don't put all your logic in the for statement.  It makes the code hard to understand.

Comment: If you provide a complete, reproducible example, we can help you convert it to python. As it is we have to make some assumptions about the data structures that you've used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C

```
for(tptr = start; tptr != NULL && tptr->data < newnode->data; prev=tptr, tptr= tptr->next);
```

is equivalent to

```
tptr = start;
while (tptr != NULL && tptr->data < newnode->data) {
  prev = tptr;
  tptr = tptr->next;
}
```

A C-style `for` loop is rather a `while` loop. Expressing it in Python with a `for` construct would be certainly possible (e.g., writing a `for` loop that runs forever and breaking out if the condition is not met), but it would not be best practice.

In Python, I would recommend to express your example with a `while` loop (unless it is a simple `for`-loop like iterating over the numbers 0 to n).